# How to get javascript method definitions/properties on hover in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I used to be able to get definitions of functions like `Array.map()` or `Array.filter()` in visual studio code. But I downloaded a fresh version of the software and forgot to sync my setting before doing so. Now I don't get such information on hover, even though I've downloaded my usual plugins. How do I fix this?

Answer (score -2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to open settings and Type “editor.hover.enable” into the search then check the checkbox associated with “Controls whether the hover is shown.” to enable the suggestion tooltip on hover.

Comment: The function is enabled, but when I over ontop of array.map() I get "any". Only when I'm typing the function then I get to see all the properties and its description

Comment: array might be `any` type or array is not defined so it's `any` type 
or however you defined in a variable, if you change array variable to number, string or other type it will show number type instaed of any.